# Todo note steals space

Tags: spacing, todonotes

I'm writing a larger document and I use the `todonotes` package to add reminders. For some reason, when I add a note, the space after the note's insertion point is removed. Here's minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[textsize=scriptsize,textwidth=2cm,shadow]{todonotes}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\todo{stolen space} consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

And here's the result I'm getting:

[image: Image of a line with a todo note]

And a blown up section of the missing space:

[image: Blown up section, where the space is missing]

I thought this might just be an artifact experienced while the notes are active,  which would be acceptable since the final document will not have any notes, so I tried to disable them by `\usepackage[disable,textsize=scriptsize,textwidth=2cm,shadow]{todonotes}`. Now the notes are gone, but the space is still missing. It's bad.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a shortcoming of the `todonotes` package?

Also, I have noticed when I add `{}` to the end of the note (`\todo{correct? spacing}{}`), the missing space magically re-appears. However, I'm not sure it's a good solution.

Comment: I think you are right. Sorry, Martin, Hendrik is correct, and so is egreg.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My best guess is that this is a *feature* of `todonotes` and that you're supposed to put a space between the `,` and `\todo`. I've tested: This gives correct spacing.

Comment: I was under the impression `\todo` worked the same way as `\footnote` so I never even tried to add a space **in front of** the command... Thanks for opening my eyes.

Comment: @Heisenb0rg: Ah, the analogy with `\footnote` is good. Didn't think of that.

Comment: @HendrikVogt The current version of the todonotes manual lists it as a known issue, so I don't think this is the choice of the author: See 1.6.2: he current version of the todonotes manual lists it as a known issue, so I don't think this is the choice of the author: See 1.6.2:

Comment: As of 2022, this appears to be fixed. Spaces are preserved after a `\todo{}` now. Apparently it was not a feature after all, but a bug.

Answer (score 20):

I short look in the source of `todonotes` reveals that both the enabled and disabled version have a `\ignorespaces` at the end, so yes, it is a *feature* not a *bug*. Apparently this is the preference of the package author.

The manual doesn't mention anything about spaces and there is no option to disable the `\ignorespaces`. Therefore you will need to add the space manually by yourself (as long you don't use your own copy of `todonotes.sty` with both `\ignorespaces` removed).

Possible ways to keep the space (some already mentioned in the other answers):

```
lorem ipsum \todo{...}dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum \todo{...} dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum\todo{...}\ dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum{\todo{...}} dolor sit amet
```

Comment: ... and `lorem ipsum \todo{...} dolor sit amet`, which I'd prefer.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yes, you are right. I added that. I think now that this is the preferred form of the package author and the reason he added `\ignorespaces`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Please, remove the suggestion of using `\xspace`; it does more damages than it helps.

Comment: @egreg: Ok, done!

Comment: @MartinScharrer The current version of the todonotes manual lists it as a known issue, so I don't think this is the choice of the author: See 1.6.2: http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf

Comment: The last one was very helpful for a macro, as an additional space might end up before punctuation. It should eat the space before it, not the one after it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also wrap `\@bsphack` ... `\@esphack` around `\todo` as described in [Patching commands to remove surrounding whitespace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68737/patching-commands-to-remove-surrounding-whitespace) and the answers explaining how to properly patch commands :)

Concretely, adding

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\todo}{\@bsphack}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\todo}{\@esphack}{}{}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble unintrusively converts `\todo` to a command that does not take up any space.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a result also observed after commands such as   `\LaTeX` where spaces are 'killed'. So even with the disable option the command is still in the code and apparently somehow interpreted.

A solution might be to add the `xspace` package and to use

```
\newcommand{\mytodo}[1]{\todo{#1}\xspace}
```

(untested)