# Patching commands to remove surrounding whitespace

Tags: spacing, todonotes, patching

I'm using the `todonotes` package to add little margin notes to my text, however writing

```
Hello\todo{test} World!
```

removes the interword space as is already pointed out in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11802/todo-note-steals-space). So I tried

```
\pretocmd{\todo}{\@bsphack}{}{}
\apptocmd{\todo}{\@esphack}{}{}
```

and this adds the interword space but simply outputs all parameters instead of passing them to `\todo`.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\todo}{\@bsphack}{}{}
\apptocmd{\todo}{\@esphack}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello\todo{test} World!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `\todo` is defined with `\newcommand` to have an optional argument, the macro to patch is really

```
\\todo
```

(with a backslash in its name), so it's difficult to specify it: you can patch it using `\csname` or do it with the `xpatch` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\todo}{\@bsphack}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\todo}{\@esphack}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello\todo{test} World!
\end{document}
```

With `etoolbox` you'd have to write

```
\expandafter\pretocmd\csname\string\todo\endcsname{\@bsphack}{}{}
\expandafter\apptocmd\csname\string\todo\endcsname{\@esphack}{}{}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do `\[be]sphack` do (or perhaps more appropriately, which package are they from)?

Comment: @SeanAllred They're defined in the LaTeX kernel

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this easier. Since the definition of `\todo` simply is

```
\newcommand{\todo}[2][]{\@todo[#1]{#2}}%
```

you can just redefine it (in a slightly safer way than the original definition, see Bruno Le Floch's comment to this answer (thanks!)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\@bsphack\@todo[{#1}]{#2}\@esphack}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Hello\todo{test} World!

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, but I was hoping to solve the problem without redefining the command explicitly so that (a) I'd learn more and (b) I'm less vulnerable to future changes to the structure of the command ;)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about (b) too much. `\todo` obviously is a simple wrapper for the actual notes command. So I guess `\todo`'s definition is unlikely going to change.

Comment: Well, the definition of `\todo` is currently not very good since the first argument cannot contain `]`.  The normal technique to include those in optional arguments is to add braces around the first argument: `\todo[{...[]...}]{...}`, but `\@todo` will see `\@todo[...[]...]{...}`, and the first argument of `\@todo` will be `[...[]` (delimited by the first `]`), which is not as expected.  A better choice would be to use `\@todo[{#1}]{#2}` in the definition of `\todo`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch `\todo` has only one option where I think that could matter: the `caption` option, but I agree. If one chooses to redefine `\todo` one should do it right. I'll edit my answer.