# How can I ignore spaces after todo items?

Tags: spacing

Consider the following (`xpatch`-fu from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68741/17423)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[marginpar]{todo}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\todo}{\@bsphack}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\todo}{\@esphack}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text %
\todo{this text shouldn't be displayed}
more text
\end{document}
```

gives (without my attempt to fix)

[image]

As you can see, the interword spacing between `text` and `more` is doubled.
Looking at the use of the macro, this makes perfect sense as to *why*,
  but this is certainly undesirable behavior (at least for the `marginpar` option).

My fix is entirely ineffective and actually inserts everything after `\todo` into the input stream. :(

How can I get the behavior I need?

---

with above `xpatch`-fu

[image: output]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the two spaces you get correspond to the the one after `Some text` and the one after the `\todo` command. Why not removing one of those two spaces?

Comment: @Jubobs That was planned.  I can't be sure that the people who use the class are going to trim trailing spaces—or even know why it's necessary—so I'm trying to bake the better behavior into the class file.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/68737/

Comment: It certainly looked like a duplicate, but unfortunately it isn't.  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@displaytodo}{\ignorespaces}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@donetodo}{\ignorespaces}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@@displaynothing}{\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother
```

and you should achieve what you want.

The macro `\todo` isn't patchable directly, so we patch all the macros called by it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[marginpar]{todo}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@displaytodo}{\ignorespaces}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@donetodo}{\ignorespaces}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\@@displaynothing}{\ignorespaces}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text %
\todo{this text shouldn't be displayed}
more text
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]