# Why does \marginpar sometimes add an unnecessary newline?

Tags: line-breaking, marginpar

In the following example, the main paragraph gets typeset as 3 lines of text, with the paragraph ending on the third line before it reaches the margin.  However, when un-commenting the line with the `\marginpar` command, the paragraph is reformatted so that the third line extends all the way to the margin, and a blank fourth line is inserted.  What is the `\marginpar` inserting into the main text that doesn't "fit" into the third line, and why?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Suppose furthermore that abcde is a regular cardinal such thati abcdefghiji
The collection abcdefg is called a 
nice collection of elementary submodels of $H(\theta)$ indexed by $T$ if,
in addition to being a nice collection of sets as above, we have:  Bake
%\marginpar{Bake a cake.}

Next paragraph.
\end{document}
```

(Note:  The `\noindent` and the choice of document class are probably not essential to the problem, but I couldn't quite get the spacing right when trying to reproduce the problem without them.)

I realize that the practical workaround is to remove the inter-word space before the `\marginpar` command.  However, it is not clear to me why this should be necessary.  Furthermore, I discovered this problem when using the `\todo` command of the `todonotes` package, which relies on `\marginpar`.  It seems that `\todo` intentionally gobbles the space following its argument, meaning that it is designed so that [one should (in general) leave a space before it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11807/21053), but this case then becomes an exception.

Answer (score 9):

The end of paragraph command (from `\par` or a blank line) attempts to remove any space at the end of the paragraph (before it does the linebreaking) by doing an `\unskip` operation. However the `insert` node for the marginpar protects the interword space so it doesn't get removed. If you are unlucky you get a linebreak and the last line of the paragraph *only* has the insert node, so gets filled with `\parfillskip` glue and has the appearance of a blank line. Put a `%` at the end of the line above and things work better. (You see the same with `\footnote` or `\index`)