# xspace leaves space in front of comment

Tags: spacing, todonotes, xspace

I am confused by the behaviour of `\xspace` in combination with the `\todo` command. I didn't expect `\xspace` to leave a space when I cut off all spaces by a comment sign `%`. Usually this works as expected, cf. counterexample.

However, in my context it doesn't work and I cannot really figure out why.

**MWE (edit: added counterexample)**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
% define mtodo WITH xspace
\newcommand{\mtodo}[1]{\todo[fancyline,noline]{#1}\xspace}
% define mmtodo WITHOUT xspace
\newcommand{\mmtodo}[1]{\todo[fancyline,noline]{#1}}
% counterexample
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{\label{#1}\xspace}

\begin{document}
  % with xspace (mtodo)
  \mtodo{Margin Note 1}%
  This is an\mtodo{Margin Note 2} example with xspace.\\
  This is an example with xspace.

  % without xspace (mmtodo)
  \mmtodo{Margin Note 1}%
  This is an\mmtodo{Margin Note 2} example without xspace.\\
  This is an example without xspace.

  % without xspace (mmtodo)
  \mylabel{label1}%
  This is a\mylabel{label1} counterexample.\\
  This is a counterexample.      
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Commands with arguments don't benefit in any way from `\xspace`. Don't use it.

Comment: @egreg I cannot 100%ly agree, since the second line shows an effect as I require it. Anyway, which alternative way do you suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\todo` is at the end of `todonotes.sty`:

```
\newcommand{\todo}[2][]{\@bsphack\@todo[#1]{#2}\@esphack\ignorespaces}%
```

The usage of `\@bsphack` means you are supposed to have a space before `\todo`, if you want that a space appears in the output. Adding `\xspace` does no good.

In any case

```
\xspace%
X
```

is the same as `\xspace X` and a space will be added because a letter follows.

So the answer is:

1. don't use `\xspace` for commands with arguments
2. leave a space before `\todo` (or macros starting with it) if you want a space appears in the output
3. use `\xspace` under no circumstances

You probably got the suggestion of `\xspace` from [Todo note steals space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11802/todo-note-steals-space) Don't follow it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these advices. I will do as you suggest. Just a note: my counterexample shows that `xspace` can work as expected in some cases even with arguments... am I wrong?

Comment: @matheburg No, it doesn't. In this case it seems to work, just because it kills the `\ignorespaces` in the definition of `\todo`.

Comment: @egreg can you write a comment/answer to your cited question not to use `\xspace`?  I think that would be a good idea ...

Comment: I have e.g. a command `\newcommand{\intodo}[1]{\color{red}[#1]\color{black}\xspace}`. Why shouldn't I use `\xspace` in this command? It really does what I want :)

Comment: @matheburg No, it does nothing at all. Better said: it could add a space when you don't want it.

Comment: @matheburg xspace after `\foo ` the space character is dropped so xpsace might possibly be useful to put a space back (but usually isn't) after `\foo{} ` the space character does make a space token so there is nothing xspace can do (and it does nothing useful)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: What about `\foo{}bar`? ...but yeah I basically agree with your argumentation. Sorry for all the confusion! :)

Comment: @matheburg blame the author of `xspace` for the confusion.

Comment: @egreg Corrected.